# Is there any C/C++ library similar to apache httpcomponents?

Tags: c++, c, http

are there any library similar to apache httpcomponents for c/c++ language?

Thanks in advance,
Dario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how similar they are to those particular Apache components, but you might want to look at [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) and [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html). Both provide quite a bit in the way of networking in C++. ACE tends to be the more all-encompassing of the two (both in terms of supporting lots of protocols and such, and in terms of tending to control/dominate all of how an application is written/works).

Depending on exactly what you're after, you could also look at [Boost.asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and/or [LibCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).

Comment: I totally forgot libcurl! For what I do is more than enough.Thank you for the other tips that will truly matter to my own study! : D